# Do interspecies couples exist in Zootopia?

Tags: zootopia

In Zootopia, we see a number of married species (Mr and Mrs. Otter and Hopps) and we even see a wedding. All of those are intraspecies relationships.

Do we see any interspecies relationships? It's hinted that Nick and Judy may be in a relationship, but is there anything explicit?

Comment: Bringing meaning to the phrase "The lion shall lie down with the lamb" since 2016....

Comment: [Confirmed] Fru-Fru is an arctic shrew, as is her husband.

Comment: Officer Francine Pennington the elephant is seen with a hippo for her birthday meal in the short film *Zootopia+ - Dinner Rush*, but it's not clear what their relationship is; https://preview.redd.it/b8qx8phhcpz91.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7c9cdfcb5b477ba9b07f48b97afb0e530e8a4379

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently so.

In the [Disney fandom wiki for Zootopia](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Zootopia), there are two characters called [Bucky and Pronk Oryx-Antlerson](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Bucky_and_Pronk_Oryx-Antlerson) who are Judy's neighbours in her apartment complex. Bucky is a [Kudu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudu) and Oryx is an [Gemsbok/Oryx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemsbok).

They have been confirmed to be a married couple in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/thejaredbush/status/803836679425556480) in 2016 by [Jared Bush](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1158544/), who was the voice actor for Pronk, as well as screenwriter and co-director for the movie, which would make it canonical.

Comment: Lol. Interspecies *in a way that requires twitter confirmation or you wouldn't know*. That's just Disney in a nutshell right there.

Answer (score 17):

Byron Howard and Rich Moore confirmed in [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDisIKoGLQM&t=145s) that not only are interspecies relationships perfectly acceptable in the world of Zootopia, but that they could also (potentially) lead to offspring.

> **Q:**... *There's one facet that's kinda interesting is that all of the romantic
> relationships are all within the same species, otter and otter, bunny and bunny that we see. And there's a general sexual objectification of Shakira's character but because she's a celebrity. But is that okay? Like
> in a sequel could Nick [and Judy]?*
>
> **Byron Howard:** *I think it's beautiful. Better than ok. Yeah. I think feels like it's like our own world, it's a very open-minded society. It feels like animals fall in love*
>
> **Rich Moore:** *Yeah, I think so. Who are we to judge?*
>
> **Q:** *So then, could Nick and Judy have a romance?*
>
> **Rich Moore:** *I feel they could*
>
> **Q:** *What would their kids be?*
>
> **Byron Howard:** *Funnies or boxes?*
>
> **Q:** *I'm glad I'm not the only one who was thinking about it.*

---

In the licenced comic [*Quick as a Flash*](https://zootopia.fandom.com/wiki/Quick_As_A_Flash!), Aa sloth, [Priscilla Tripletoe](https://zootopia.fandom.com/wiki/Priscilla_Tripletoe), is asked out on a date by a handsome hyena. Based on his leer, I think we can assume that he's after more than just friendship and popcorn.

> [image]

Comment: Yes, but the important question is: would the offspring be fertile?

Comment: @lfurini - That's the important question? Really?

Comment: If the offspring is fertile then, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species), foxes and bunnies (and probably all animals) are the _same_ species in the world of Zootopia, so Nick and Judy are _not_ an interspecies couple; on the other hand, the offspring being infertile would cast a dark shadow upon interspecies couples being a good thing ... (joking, of course)

Comment: @lfurini Not quite, they'd only be the same species if *any pair* of foxes and bunnies could have fertile offspring, not if Nick and Judy specifically had fertile offspring. Horses and donkeys are different species and *usually* produce infertile offspring, but the fact that some mules are indeed fertile does not imply that horses and donkeys are the same species.

Comment: @lfurini While it is generally a rule, the rule has exceptions. An interesting type of exception is that of "ring species", where species A and B can produce fertile offspring, species B and C can produce fertile offspring, but A and C cannot. In this case, you cannot say that A and B are the same species and B and C are the same species, because that would imply that A and C are the same species. The greenish warbler ring species, Ensatina salamanders ring species, and Larus gulls ring species are three examples of this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species

Comment: @lfurini To expand on what Ben was saying, that Wikipedia article you link starts out saying "often defined as", and includes a Definition section that has 11 different ways species are defined in biology, as well as an entire section following that describing the difficulties of defining "species", because it's such a complicated concept.

Comment: Weird. The answer should have been "well, it's a cartoon, so, sure, if you want, but that's also weird." But all things are OK, for an "open society", I guess. This is like when Ratatouille went weird part way though in the scene with rat traps "oh, but humans want to kill you, Remi". Yes, I guess, but that's a weird way to take the story in a kids cartoon. *Too much* realism and worldbuilding.